# how to show custom buttons on vf block sections

Tags: visualforce, pageblocksection

i have created a vf page which requires a custom button formatting

[image]

i want to show buttons "go" and "send payslip" exactly bottom of those two picklists.
Here is my vf-

```
<!------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*Author: Samruddhi
*Page Name: PayslipInMonth
*Created Date: 01/12/2017
*Description: To display and send payslip according to month and year selected
Author               Date               Description
PayslipInMonth    01/12/2017      To display and send payslip according to month and year selected
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->

<apex:page standardController="Payslip__c" extensions="DisplayPayslipController" tabStyle="Print_Payslip__tab">
     <apex:sectionHeader title="Send Payslip"/>
    <apex:form id="frmid">
        <apex:pagemessages />

        <apex:pageBlock id="pg1" title="All Payslips in one List for the Month">
             <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
               <apex:outputLabel ></apex:outputLabel><apex:outputLabel ></apex:outputLabel>                                


               <apex:selectList value="{!strSelected1}" id="listYears"  size="1" label="Select Year :" multiselect="false">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!options1}">
                        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!getrecords}"/>
                    </apex:selectOptions>
                </apex:selectList>


                 <apex:selectList value="{!strSelected}" id="listMonths"  size="1" label="Select Month :" multiselect="false">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!options}">
                        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!getrecords}" reRender="s"/>
                    </apex:selectOptions>
                </apex:selectList>
               </apex:pageBlockSection>              

               <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">    

                 <apex:commandButton value="Go" action="{!getrecords}"/>

                 <apex:commandButton value="Send Payslip" action="{!send}"/>           

               </apex:pageBlockSection>
                <!-- <apex:commandButton value="Send PDF" action="{!URLFOR($Action.Payslip__c.Send_Pay_Slip,Payslip__c.id)}"/>-->



         <apex:outputPanel id="s">

            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!listWrapper}" var="w">
                <apex:column > 
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!allBool}">
                        </apex:inputCheckbox>
                    </apex:facet>
                    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!w.checked}"/>
                </apex:column> 
                <apex:column value="{!w.le.Employee__c}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!w.le.test_Payslip__c}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!w.le.Techila_Total_Earnings__c}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!w.le.Total_Deduction__c}"/>
                 <apex:column value="{!w.le.Techila_Net_Pay__c}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!w.le.Techila_Sub_Total__c}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!w.le.Sent_Date__c}"/>


            </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:outputPanel>

        </apex:pageBlock>


        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                <apex:outputLabel >* Note : Make Sure you have generated payslip for the month and the year, otherwise "Calculate Salary" first.</apex:outputLabel>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: Try to apply CSS styling to the Custom button

Comment: You can align all your fields by using [page block section items](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_pageBlockSectionItem.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to wrap your selectList and your commandButton in one div and then play with styles to align them:

```
<div class="myClassForPlayingWithStyles">
   <apex:selectList value="{!strSelected1}" id="listYears"  size="1" label="Select Year :" multiselect="false">
   <apex:selectOptions value="{!options1}">
   <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!getrecords}"/>
   </apex:selectOptions>
   </apex:selectList>
   <apex:commandButton value="Go" action="{!getrecords}"/>
</div>
```